# Rails4.2 item.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clockwork

clockworkで定期処理を実装したのですが、定期処理を開始すると下記のエラーが出ます。
cronで回していた時は同じコードでもエラーは出ませんでした。

```
I, [2015-05-19T16:10:11.003250 #15901]  INFO -- : Triggering '10.second.job'
item.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
```

どうすればエラーがでないようになるでしょうか
ちなみに定期処理は正しく動いていません

※cronであればエラーはでずに正しく定期処理が開始されます。

## lib/tasks/item.rb

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/item"

class Tasks::Item
  def self.item_check

    #処理

  end
end
```

## config/clock.rb

```
require 'clockwork'
include Clockwork

every(10.second, '10.second.job') do
  Dir.chdir("../lib/tasks"){ puts `ruby item.rb` }

end
```

## cron時の設定　config/schedule.rb　gem 'whenever'を使用

```
set :environment, :development
set :output, {:error => 'log/error.log', :standard => 'log/cron.log'}


every 1.minute do
  runner "Tasks::Item.item_check"
end
```

Comment: cronでも`ruby item.rb`ではエラーになるはずですが。　恐縮ですがcronの設定行を出してもらえますか? 何かシェルスクリプト挟んでいればその内容も。 (そもそもitem_checkは、どこから呼ばれているのでしょう?)

Comment: cronの場合はscheduleに登録してbundle exec whenever --update-cronで登録しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ruby item.rb`とやっているので。純粋なrubyから実行しています。
そのためRails環境で起動していないのでRails未定義でエラーとなります。

wheneverの場合は、`runner`で起動していますが。
これは`rails runner`が起動します。

every(10.second, '10.second.job') do
  Dir.chdir("../lib/tasks"){ puts `ruby item.rb` }

end

https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/79e4f66fba8956efe41cf919f623a247f3ef3463/lib/whenever/setup.rb

`ruby item.rb` ではなく
`rails runner -e development 'Tasks::Item.item_check'`が正しい記述となります。

※ ところでlib/tasks下ならrake taskで起動すべきじゃないですかね？

### 方法1: rails runner経由で対応する(その1)

config/clock.rb

```
Dir.chdir("../lib/tasks"){ puts `ruby item.rb` }
↓
`rails runner -e development 'require "./lib/tasks/item"; Tasks::Item.item_check'`
```

lib/tasks/item.rb

```
class Tasks::Item
↓
class Tasks
  class Item
```

### 方法2: rails runner経由で対応する(その2)

config/clock.rb

```
Dir.chdir("../lib/tasks"){ puts `ruby item.rb` }
↓
`rails runner -e development ./lib/tasks/item.rb'
```

lib/tasks/item.rb

```
class Tasks::Item
↓
class Tasks
  class Item
ファイルの最後に、Tasks::Item.item_checkの呼び出しを書く。
※ 注意：こういったファイルは、lib/tasksに置くべきファイルではありません。
```

### 方法3:(推奨！) rake tasks経由で対応する

config/clock.rb

```
Dir.chdir("../lib/tasks"){ puts `ruby item.rb` }
↓
`rake item:check`
```

lib/tasks/item.rake
`rails g task item check`でひな形が出来る

```
namespace :item do
  desc "TODO"
  task check: :environment do
    # 処理を書く。environmentが指定されているのでapp/modelsのrequireは不要
  end
end
```

lib/tasksの下は、基本的にrakeタスクを、配置する場所です。
rubyやrunnerから直接呼び出すコードを置くべき場所では、ありません。

Comment: wheneverは動くことは確認しています。clockworkによって動作させたいのですが

Comment: ですから「whenever」から「runner」していますよね。そのrunnerの記述は、rails runnerの起動です。rails起動しているからRails.rootが使えるのであって、rails起動しないならconstant Railsが出るのは当然です。clockworkとは関係ありません。

Comment: それから質問タイトルとエラー出力が「uninitialized constant Tasks」と「uninitialized constant Rails」と一致していません。ruby item.rbしているのですからuninitialized constant Railsが正しいはずですが、質問内容も再度確認してもらえますか？

Comment: wheneverではなく、clockworkで定期処理を実行させたいんです。

Comment: ですから clockwork からruby経由ではなくrails(rake)経由で起動させてください。
とりあえず。rake対応のlib/tasks/item.rakeを回答しますからお待ちください。 (rubyだろうがrunnerだろうがlib/tasksにrbファイル置くもんじゃないので)

Comment: environment指定されているので全てのモデルがロードの対象となりますので。特に追加の記述等は不要です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事動かすことができました。感謝しています。